# Div tag height issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following div tag : (container for more html)

This is the most outer div tag.

```
<div id="top">
    <h1 style="float:left;margin:0;font-family:Impact;color:#9A3334;border:0px;padding:0px;">EasyCounter</h1>
    <label style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
        <meteor-include src="loginButtons" style="color:black;font-size:14pt;"></meteor-include>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="main-content">

    <div id="left">
        <button id="meal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static">Add Meal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"> <!--1-->
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <!--2-->
                <div class="modal-content" ng-controller="formCtrl"> <!--3-->
                    <div class="modal-header"> <!--4-->
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="clear()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Meal</h2>
                    </div> <!--/4-->

                    <div class="modal-body"> <!--5-->
                        <label>Description :
                            <input type="text" ng-model="meal.description">
                        </label>
                        <div ng-repeat="item in meal.items"> <!--6-->
                            <label>Item {{$index+1}} :
                                <input type="text" class="item" ng-model="item.name"><br>
                            </label>
                            <label>Calories :
                                <input type="number" class="calories" ng-model="item.cal"><br>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                        </div> <!--/6-->

                    <div class="modal-footer"> <!--7-->
                        <button ng-click="clear()" style="box-shadow:none;outline:none;" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
                        <button ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">+Item</button>
                    </div> <!--/7-->

                </div> <!--/5-->
             </div> <!--/3-->
          </div> <!--/2-->
        </div><!--/1-->
        <!--/Modal-->

    </div> <!--/left-->

    <div id="right" ng-controller="resultCtrl">
        <label id="date">
            Today's Date : {{todayDate}}
        </label>
    </div>

</div><!--/main-content-->
```

This is my CSS:

```
html,body {
 font-family: "garamond";
 height: 100%;
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}

#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F3EFE0;
  border: 5px white solid;
}

#left {
  margin-top:100px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#right {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 650px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 550px;
}

#meal-button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #217C7E;
  border-color:transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "garamond";
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

#date {
  text-align:center;
  font-family:garamond;
  font-size:25pt;
  color:white;
  height:50px;
  width:550px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #9A3334;
}
```

My application will be basically be containing a table that will be getting longer and longer as the user adds data to it. I thought the following CSS would work and I set a border just for a visual plus for testing sake and for some reason, it did not cover the entire page. Only until the end of my HTML elements inside the main-content container. Why is this happening?

I want the background to cover the entire page. This is what is happening currently:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a fiddle please?

Comment: html,body{height:100%} and all oparent div's of the div you are targetting should also be 100%

Comment: make your body/html 100% in height as well. Should do the trick.
`body,html {height:100%;}`

Comment: Um why would I make all oparent divs of the div height of 100%? Its actually using a popover w/bootstrap so I don't think that is needed? Not sure just my reasoning. I attempted making body 100% and still didn't work

Comment: from your last line, do you mean that your `#main-content` div does not cover entire page even if there is data to full page length, Or '#main-content' div does not cover full page height when empty or no data inside of it?

Comment: Did you make just the `body` 100%, or both the `body` and the `html` as suggested twice?

Comment: I want the main content div to cover the entire page and then as the user adds data, the table will grow and depending on that, I want the page to keep going down. And yeah, I did what Ahs suggested below. Strange that his is working but mine isn't. That's the way I was looking for too.

Comment: Just put up a picture in my post as a visual to what's happening

Comment: @halapgos1 Please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue in your question. If Ahs N's solution appears to be working in his example then there is likely something in your code that is causing it not to work.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Just put up my code

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by Deepak and timo above, this should work:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F3EFE0;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5kb0zwjc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the bootom of your html page just before where your `body` tag ends -

```
<script>    
    var canvasHeight = $(window).height();    
    $(document).ready(function (){    
        $('#main-content').css('min-height', canvasHeight)    
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: This works and I thought of possibly using something like this too, but I'm kind of interested in terms of finding out what is wrong w/my CSS though. Thank you though!

Comment: May be not this, but do you have any universal selector `*` is defined in your css and set within it `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0`?